# can c++ class attributes be conditionally compiled

Tags: c++, enable-if

Say I want to make 2 versions of a class - a thread safe version which will use lock guards on all mutating operations, and a 'thread dangerous' one which won't and will presumably run faster in a single-threaded client.

A bit like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <mutex>

template <bool THREADSAFE>
class wibble {
    private:
    typename std::enable_if<THREADSAFE, std::mutex>::type mtx_;
};

wibble<true> threadsafe; // ok
wibble<false> thread_dangerous; // compiler error
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is what specialization is for.

Comment: This is currently not possible. Composition and template specialization are possible solutions.

Comment: I personally feel like C++ should allow `void` type data members which are simply not objects (no size or storage, not addressable). Then you could for example use `std::conditional_t<THREADSAFE, std::mutex, void>`.

Comment: You could write your own `fake::mutex`, where  `lock()` and `unlock()` doesn't do anything. That would be pretty fast. (As would probably a normal mutex that is never contended).

Comment: If you don't need to mix the two, there is always preprocessor #defines.  #ifdef THREADSAFE_BUILD  ...safety code,,, #else  ...unsafe code... #endif

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to achieve this is via conditional derivation:
https://godbolt.org/z/ahxGqj76c

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <type_traits>


struct threadsafe_base
{
    mutable std::mutex mtx_;
};

struct threadunsafe_base
{};

//public derivation used for brevity
template<bool THREADSAFE>
struct wibble : std::conditional_t<THREADSAFE, threadsafe_base, threadunsafe_base> 
{};

template<typename T>
void doStuff(const T& arg)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(arg.mtx_);
    //do sth
}

int main(int, char*[])
{

    wibble<true> threadsafe;
    wibble<false> thread_dangerous;

    doStuff(threadsafe);
    // doStuff(thread_dangerous); //this should fail to compile
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks again! you're much better at C++ than me. not that that's saying much ;-)